# How to show that the following set is open,

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and let  $\{f_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$ be a uniformly
bounded and equicontinuous family of functions on $X$. Define $$f(x) = \sup_{\alpha \in A} f_{\alpha}(x)$$ 
Then, for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x \in X \ : \ f(x) < t \}$ is an open set in $X$.

My attempt: The set  $$\{x \in X \ : \ f(x) < t \} \implies \cap_{\alpha}\{x \in X \ : \ f_{\alpha}(x) < t    \} $$ As each $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ is continuous, so each set of the form $$\{x \in X \ : \ f_{\alpha}(x) < t    \}$$ is open. But arbitrary intersection of open sets is not open. How to see? Where i am wrong.

Comment: That's not an intersection but an union. If the supremum is less than $t$ so is all the $f_\alpha$.

Comment: @Yanko If he meant equality, then it is not a union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not made use of the equicontinuity of the family ${\cal F}$.

Let a $t\in{\mathbb R}$ be given, and let $p\in X$ be an element of the set $S_t:=\{x\in X\,|\, f(x)<t\}$. Let $$\epsilon:={t-f(p)\over2}>0\ .$$
By equicontinuity of the $f_\alpha$ there is  a $\delta>0$ such that
$$f_\alpha(x)\leq f_\alpha(p)+\epsilon \leq f(p)+\epsilon \quad\forall x\in U_\delta(p), \>\forall\alpha\in A\ .$$
Consider now an arbitrary $x\in U_\delta(p)$. Then we can say that
$$f(x):=\sup_{\alpha\in A} f_\alpha(x)\leq f(p)+\epsilon<t\ .$$
This shows that $U_\delta(p)\subset S$, and proves that $S_t$ is open.

It turns out that the compactness of $X$ was not needed.

Comment: Christian blatter....Can you plz tell me how do you get "By equicontinuity of the $f_\alpha$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$f_\alpha(x) \le f_\alpha(p)+\epsilon \forall x \in U_\delta(p), \forall \alpha$$ ".......? I cannot understand this line... I know that by equicontinuity we get an $\delta>0$ such that $|f_\alpha(x_0)-f_\alpha(y_0)|<\epsilon$..blah blah...

Comment: ...I read the definition of equicontinuity from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity now...So here $\{f_\alpha\}$ is equicontinuous at $p$ . So for $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta$ such that every point $x$ near $p$ , $f_\alpha(x)$ becomes in between $\epsilon$ distance from $f_\alpha(p)$ for all $\alpha$.....am I right...?? and if so we get $$\forall x \in U_\delta(p), |f_\alpha(x)-f_\alpha(p)|, \forall \alpha$$....and then we get $f_\alpha(x) < f_\alpha(p)+ \epsilon$....Am I right..??

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh: That's it!

Comment: Thank you so much...